# how to associate vibration with a button click

Tags: objective-c

I have to following code

```
-(IBAction)doVibrate{
    [self vibrate];
}
-(void)vibrate{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
}
```

both `doVibrate` and vibrate are is same class .but when i am clicking the button associated to the `doVibrate` it device not vibrating .
I have imported the `AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h` and `AVFoundation/AVFoundation`.

Can some one tell me where i am wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IBActions are usually of the following form:

```
- (IBAction)vibrate:(id)sender;
```

Note that the following 3 methods are all different:

```
- (IBAction)vibrate:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)vibrate; // no sender argument
- (void)doVibrate;
```

Here is what I would do. In your .h file, define the following method:

```
- (IBAction)vibrate:(id)sender;
// - (IBAction)vibrate;  comment out this method
```

In your .m file, do the following:

```
- (IBAction)vibrate:(id)sender {
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
}
```

Now, when you save your .h and .m files, and switch back to your nib/xib file in Interface Builder, it may show a yellow warning message that "'vibrate' is no longer defined in "your class name here'. That's okay, as the following should remove that error. Control-click (or right-click) on the button and drag to your controller class and choose "vibrate:" as the method name to call (note the colon, :, in the method name).

Comment: Thanks for the response .Actually i was trying vibration in ipod touch but as we know ipods doesnt vibrates so there is no issue.